# Mysql OperationalError 1044, connect to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

f_dbI am trying to connect to mysql database using a python script. My code to do so is the following:

```
 `db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xx.xx.xx", # your host, usually localhost
                 port = xxxx,
                 user="chrathan", # your username
                 passwd="...", # your password
                 db="f_db") # name of the data base`
```

I ve open the database from mysql workbench. However, I am not able to open it from python I am getting the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'chrathan'@'%' to database 'f_db'"). Basically I am receiving `Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\_WORKSPACE\mysql\fashion_db.py", line 7, in <module>
db = 'f_db') mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'chrathan'@'%' to database 'f_db'")`
```

Comment: I found that the error stands for the database name. When I remove that  line it works! Thus the problem lies with the final line and the name of the database.

Comment: I workbench I connected with that information.Why now I am getting  Access denied for user 'chrathan'@'%' to database 'f_db'

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information that you provided in your comments. Comments are NOT for this type of usage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enter this command on mysql terminal

```
$> mysql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON f_db.* TO 'chrathan'@'%' identified by 'secret'
```

for add user to database in mysqlworkbench look at this page [How to Create a MySQL Database with MySQL Workbench](http://webvaultwiki.com.au/%28S%28iungfwenvz2f5c55pioeinil%29%29/Default.aspx?Page=Create-Mysql-Database-User-Workbench&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: mysql command in mysql utilities console it gives me the utility mysql in not accessible from the path c\programfiles\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6, and GRANT .. it gives me unknown command.

Comment: Basically I am having install mysql workbench, I found that mysql.exe exists in c\programfiles\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.1.4,

Comment: I ve already add the user in workbench but i cannot access database from python. My issue is with python, workbench works fine.

Comment: @FereRes look at the end of page and see user and privileges

Comment: In db when I click in user and privilages it shows me the account you are currently using does not have sufficient privilages to make changes to mysql users and privilages.

Comment: Actually it is not a local database, I ve got to change the privilages from the server, I am guessing right?

Comment: I ve change the privilages finally, however now I am receiving a new error message: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'fashion'")

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should check db name whether is same, the same problem occour on me, finally i found mysqlclient db name is not same as i use in python