# What could be the problem of django run error

Tags: django

My Django project used to work well the day before but it was not working when I run the next day. The following is the error I am getting. I didn't change anything and yet it did not work. When  I run my project, the following error occurs. The project name is 'carpooling' and the the database user is 'Jigme'. I think the last line points the error towards the database which I didn't change anything.
Please help me. Your help will be appreciated.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'jigme'@'%' to database 'carpooling'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'jigme'@'%' to database 'carpooling'")
```

Comment: Check this question: [Using MySQL with Django - Access denied for user '@'localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170133/using-mysql-with-django-access-denied-for-user-localhost)

Comment: Seems duplicate of - [Mysql OperationalError 1044, connect to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736697/mysql-operationalerror-1044-connect-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Thank you @Abdul Aziz Barkat and  Sumit Badsara . this solution worked for me